# Python Selenium Able to Find Elements But Can't Find them Using Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm fluent with using python selenium, but it didn't work on the new facebook design page

[image]

If anyone have the new facebook page please check if you can detect any element using python on this page : https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/

for example looking for this xpath : `//li[@class='_5l-3 _1ht1 _6zk9']`, in browser we'll find 30 elements. but in python when we run our script it won't work :

[image]

here is my code :

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
opt.add_argument("start-maximized")
opt.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_mic": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.media_stream_camera": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 2,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2
    })
global driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("yourpathtochromedriver", options=opt)

time.sleep(5)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")

username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
username.send_keys('youremail')
username = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='pass']")
username.send_keys('yourpassword')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@name='login']").click()

driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/messages/t")
time.sleep(3)

test = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='_5l-3 _1ht1 _6zk9']")
count = (len(test))
print(count)
```

Comment: does it throwing any error?

Answer (score 1):

I have run into similar issues before and what worked for me was using the `WebDriverWait` class.  From my experience, this issue is happening because you are trying to retrieve the elements from the page before it is even loaded.  You can use `WebDriverWait` to wait for the presence of the element to be detected then retrieve it.

Comment: Hello Salty, i don't think this is the issue, i've tried it with webdriver and the page was all loaded and still can't detect the elements

Comment: Oh, them I do not know how to help, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

1. I fail to find element `"//li[@class='_5l-3 _1ht1 _6zk9']"` on page https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/.
   **So provide some more error log please.**
2. it is not a good idea `"//li[@class='_5l-3 _1ht1 _6zk9']"`, try something like this `"//li[contains(@class,'_5l-3') and contains(@class,'_1ht1') and contains(@class,'_6zk9')]"`, or cssSelector expression `"li._5l-3._1ht1._6zk9"`.